# Can my tortoise vs. hare race be improved?

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, code-duplication, control-flow

Here is my code for detecting cycles in a linked list:

```
do
{
    hare = hare.next();
    if (hare == back) return;

    hare = hare.next();
    if (hare == back) return;

    tortoise = tortoise.next();
}
while (tortoise != hare);
throw new AssertionError("cyclic linkage");
```

1. Is there a way to get rid of the code duplication inside the loop?
2. Am I right in assuming that I don't need a check after making the tortoise take a step forward? As I see it, the tortoise can never reach the end of the list before the hare (contrary to the fable).
3. Any other ways to simplify/beautify this code?

Comment: If you design `back` to refer to a node with a "next" field pointing to itself, then you can replace 4 lines with `hare = hare.next().next(); if (hare==back) return;`. Don't know if I'm allowed to change the list, though.

Comment: @Steve: `back` can directly refer to itself (it's already a sentinel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my improved code based on Steve's comment (having the back sentinel node link to itself):

```
while (hare != back)
{
    tortoise = tortoise.next();
    hare = hare.next().next();
    if (hare == tortoise) throw new AssertionError("cyclic linkage");
}
```

I don't see any place where this would break client code, and my unit tests confirm that. Great :)

Comment: Doesn't this give a false positive for a list of length 1? Unfortunately you need to check `hare` against `back` before checking it against `tortoise`.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to get rid of the code
>   duplication inside the loop?

How about:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    hare = hare.next();
    if (hare == back) return;
}

 tortoise = tortoise.next();
```

That isn't a massive improvement by any means.

> Am I right in assuming that I don't need a check after making the tortoise take a step forward?

Yes, as you correctly reason, the tortoise is always behind the hare just *before* it moves; so the tortoise is always covering ground that has been covered before.

If the data-structure were for any reason mutated during the race, this would of course no longer be true (but if so, you would have much bigger problems).

> Any other ways to simplify/beautify
>   this code?

Not that I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single if-statement and use the fact that `||` is a short-circuit operator. This is a bit more concise, but may be harder to understand and there is still code duplication.

```
    do
    {
        if ((hare = hare.next()) == back || 
            (hare = hare.next()) == back) 
                return;            
        tortoise = tortoise.next();
    }
    while (tortoise != hare);
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the duplication, you could use a `for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)` loop. Other than that, I think you've pretty much got the simplest code you can have right there.